# Haaah.........I need to know how to set up my MetaMask to Ethereum

Tags: blockchain, metamask

I just need to know how to set up my MetaMask to Ethereum,I need your assist because im very new person using this platform/software.
Thank you i hope you will reply my question very soon.

Answer (score 0):

This video should get you started with MetaMask.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ZgFijd02Jo&t=3s

Comment: ok..........but been watch the video it nice and understandable.